# Стоит ли использовать вторую версию Yii?

Tags: yii

Здравствуйте! Собираюсь на писать сайт используя yii - фреймверк. Узнал, что есть вторая (бета) версия. Хотел спросить у знатоков, стоит ли использовать её или использовать 1.1.15 ? Спасибо.

Comment: Лучше вторую. Первая сама по себе во многом была не очень хороша, вторая, хотя бы, composer-based и соблюдает общие стандарты.

Comment: а вообще какой фреймверк советуюте?

Comment: Symfony 2юч

Answer (score 1):

Yii2 это полностью новый фреймворк. Все что написано на 1-ом точно не пойдет на 2-ом. Я использую 1 для совместимости. Скажем если заказывать веб-хостинг там часто php 5.0 стоит. соответственно все плюшки типа $array = []; // не прокатят . Скорее всего yii2 еще не дожил  до момента повсеместного внедрения. А так на VPS можно поставить.

Comment: @exru php 5.0? серьезно? Уже все нормальные хостинги на 5.4

Comment: Серьезно! допустим хостинг на webnames ;-)

Comment: А в остальном настолько хороший хостинг?  

*На моём с 5.5 уже давно играться можно..*

Comment: @xEdelweiss

> На моём с 5.5 уже давно играться можно..

не забудьте распечатать и повесить на окне, чтобы об этом знали не только мы, но и все прохожие.

Comment: @Etki, я подумаю над этим, но не обещаю. А вам могу предложить огнетушитель.
@exru, прошу прощения за бессмысленную ветку под вашим ответом.

Comment: Ребят я все понимаю, но по моему я ответ адекватный дал.

Comment: @exru я вам рекомендую поменять хостинг

Comment: @exru, 5.0 действительно вышла очень давно, и там а) нет многих вещей, который упрощают жизнь и б) большинство современных фреймворков просто не запустятся на 5.0, потому что они как раз-таки используют эти штуки (например, неймспейсы или короткую нотацию массивов). В принципе, я не уверен, что там действительно 5.0 - уж очень старый релиз.

Answer (score 0):

Сейчас пишу проект на Yii2. Пока никаких проблем не встретил. Документация по фреймворку есть